# Mongoose aggregate - $subtract dates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having troubles with Mongoose aggregation when trying to subtract two dates to get milliseconds of the difference.

Here's the document's structure:

```
DeliverySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  hash: String,
  status: Number,
  insertedOn: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  endedOn: {
    type: Date
  }
}, {
  collection: 'Deliveries'
});
```

This is the query:

```
var Delivery = mongoose.model('Delivery');

return Delivery.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        'insertedOn': {$ne: null, $type: 9},
        'endedOn': {$ne: null, $type: 9}
      }
    },
    {$project: {duration: {$subtract: ["$endedOn", "$insertedOn"]}}},
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          day: {$dayOfMonth: "$insertedOn"},
          month: {$month: "$insertedOn"},
          year: {$year: "$insertedOn"}
        },
        count: {$sum: 1},
        durationAvg: {$avg: "$duration"}
      }
    },
    {$sort: {"_id.year": 1, "_id.month": 1, "_id.day": 1}}
  ])
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
error: exception: can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date
```

The $match phase should filter all documents with insertedOn/endedOn fields null or non-Date, but it seems useless. I'm stuck, does anybody have any clues?
I'm using Mongoose 4.0.1 (mongod 2.6.9 hosted on Mongolab) with Node 0.10.33.
Thanks

Thanks.

Comment: One way this can happen is if you have a doc where either `insertedOn` or `endedOn` contains an _array_ that contains a `Date`.  Also, `null` is separate type, so you shouldn't need the `$ne: null` parts in the `$match` object.

Comment: You're right, the `$ne: null` part of `$match` is useless. None of my documents contains arrays of date though, in fact i also tried with a single document with both `insertedOn` and `endedOn` fields populated with a  Date and i'm getting exactly the same error.

Comment: OK, I think I see the problem now.  You need to include the `insertedOn` and `endedOn` fields in your `$project`.  As it is now, its just the single `duration` field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of your `$project` stage is docs that contain only the computed `duration` field.  You need to also include the `insertedOn` and `endedOn` fields so that they're available for use in the `$group` stage that follows:

```
{$project: {
    duration: {$subtract: ["$endedOn", "$insertedOn"]},
    endedOn: 1,
    insertedOn: 1
}}
```

Comment: Yeah. That's the solution. Thanks @JohnnyHK, you saved my day :-)